# Combine Checked Items Into One Cell

Tags: excel, function

I need some help with something that I think should be possible to make using functions in excel. I want to be able to have a box that will display a part name, but if two of these parts are selected, will list both.
To get into more specifics, I have checkboxes linked to empty boxes, which then show TRUE or FALSE after being linked.

To make it a bit more clear, Cells B47:B54 all list FALSE, because their cooresponding checkboxes are all unchecked. Next to these, C47:C54 list "item 1","item 2", etc, down to "item 8" in cell C54. I need a way to have the TRUE/FALSE state boxes work as a toggle for which cells of C47:C54 will be concatenated into one cell.

So if I check B47 and B48, they will become TRUE, and thus in a single cell, "Item 1, Item 2" would be listed. I have been experimenting with "IF", "AND", "OR", and "CONCATENATE" in a bunch of ways, but I can't come up with anything on my own. This is probably the closest thing I've come up with: `=IF(AND(B47=TRUE,B48=TRUE),CONCATENATE(D47,D48))`

But as mentioned, that doesn't do exactly what I need, because I need it not to be limited to the cells I listed in the function. The above only links to those specific cells; I need this to work for any of the cells that are TRUE, and to concatenate those true cells into a single cell, to list the information that could be linked to the cells. I hope this is specific enough to not be flagged as "not specific enough," it's just somewhat complicated for me to explain, especially since I can't yet link pictures. However, it should work on any true values. Due to the nature of the reason I am making this, I know that the largest amount of these items/parts that will be selected will be 2 at once.

So to make it as simple as I can: I need a cell that will list the names of up to two parts when those parts' checkboxes are checked. If one is checked, one item name appears in that cell. If two checkboxes are checked, I need both of those item names to appear in the cell.

Comment: this is definitely possible, however, it would take me sometime to work out the exact solution. The answer would involve a index(match array formula. This could give you the row numbers of the true values, then using indirect you could pull the values into concat along a couple of cells in one row

Comment: Take a look at Post #8 here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/365691-concatenate-multiple-cells-array-formula.html